# Machine learning testing data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am new to machine learning and it might be a bit of a stupid question.

I have implemented my model and its working. I have a question about running it on testing data. It's a binary classification problem. If I know the proportions of classes in test data how could I use it to improve my model or improve predictions made by the model?
So let's say 75% belong to class 1 and 25% to class 0 of the testing data.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: the split in train dataset is what matters... you should make sure that enough records are present for each of the classes to train the model.. the records should not be unbalanced in train dataset. This question is more suited for the https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ community..

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad and arguably quite unclear, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also, this is not a `python` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing first is that your data should be balanced. And often in machine learning problem paradigm test data is treated as something that you know nothing about.
Any kind of information regarding improving your model by using some held out dataset is done by validation dataset.
Look for Validation Dataset. Why you need Validation Dataset, Balancing of the dataset. These terms will help you to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

There has been two different approaches to addressing imbalanced data: algorithm-level and data-level approach.

**Algorithm approach:** As mentioned above, ML algorithms penalize False Positives and False Negatives equally. A way to counter that is to modify the algorithm itself to boost predictive performance on minority class. This can be executed through either recognition-based learning or cost-sensitive learning. Feel free to check Drummond & Holte (2003); Elkan (2001); and Manevitz & Yousef (2001) in case you want to learn more about the topic.

**Data approach:** This consists of re-sampling the data in order to mitigate the effect caused by class imbalance. The data approach has gained popular acceptance among practitioners as it is more flexible and allows for the use of latest algorithms. The two most common techniques are over-sampling and under-sampling.

**Over-sampling** increases the number of minority class members in the training set. The advantage of over-sampling is that no information from the original training set is lost, as all observations from the minority and majority classes are kept. On the other hand, it is prone to overfitting.
**Under-sampling,** on contrary to over-sampling, aims to reduce the number of majority samples to balance the class distribution. Since it is removing observations from the original data set, it might discard useful information.

for more reference visit: https://medium.com/james-blogs/handling-imbalanced-data-in-classification-problems-7de598c1059f